# How to convert dynamically scaled UIFont back to original UIFont?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextview

I am working on a text editor app which involves encoding and decoding of NSAttributedString. I am using UITextView to show and edit text. I made NSAttributedString codable using NSKeyedArchiver.

```
class AttributedStringCodable : Codable {

    var attributedString : NSAttributedString

    init(nsAttributedString : NSAttributedString) {
        self.attributedString = nsAttributedString
    }

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let singleContainer = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        guard let attributedString = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(singleContainer.decode(Data.self)) as? NSAttributedString else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: singleContainer, debugDescription: "Data is corrupted")
        }
        self.attributedString = attributedString
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var singleContainer = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try singleContainer.encode(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: attributedString, requiringSecureCoding: false))
    }
}
```

I want to support dynamic type font in my app. So when user increases font size from settings my attributed string gets bigger. The problem is when I save(encode) my NSAttributedString, it saves it along with the dynamically scaled font. So next time when I open my app and load(decode) the attributed text with some different dynamic text setting, the app crashes giving this message "A scaled font returned by UIFontMetrics should not be used to create another scaled font.".
I know this happens because I am trying to create another scaled font from an already scaled font. So I want to go back to original font before I save(encode) the attributed string.
E.g.

```
let originalFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .bold)

let traitCollection = UITraitCollection(preferredContentSizeCategory: .accessibilityLarge)
let dynamicFont = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: originalFont, compatibleWith: traitCollection)

print(originalFont.pointSize)
print(dynamicFont.pointSize)
```

Now how do I convert dynamicFont back to originalFont?     Is there any alternative approach to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

So my approach would be to pair the originalFont with traitCollection in a cache array that can be decode and encode. Looked simple at first but then remember you cannot decode UIFont & UIContentSizeCategory. This may not be the best approach but there you go.

```
struct CustomFontHolder: Decodable {
    
    var id: String
    let originalSize: CGFloat
    let originalWeight: CustomFontWeight
    let traitCollection: ContentSizeCategory
    
    var originalFont: UIFont {
        return UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: originalSize, weight: originalWeight.systemFontWeight)
    }
    
    var dynamicFont: UIFont {
        return UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(
            for: originalFont,
            compatibleWith: UITraitCollection(preferredContentSizeCategory: traitCollection.category)
        )
    }
}

enum CustomFontWeight: Decodable {
    case ultraLight
    case thin
    case light
    case regular
    case medium
    case semibold
    case bold
    case heavy
    case black
    
    var systemFontWeight: UIFont.Weight {
        switch self {
        case .ultraLight: return .ultraLight
        case .thin: return .thin
        case .light: return .light
        case .regular: return .regular
        case .medium: return .medium
        case .semibold: return .semibold
        case .bold: return .bold
        case .heavy: return .heavy
        case .black: return .black
        }
    }
}

public enum ContentSizeCategory: Decodable {
    case unspecified
    case extraSmall
    case small
    case medium
    case large
    case extraLarge
    case extraExtraLarge
    case extraExtraExtraLarge
    case accessibilityMedium
    case accessibilityLarge
    case accessibilityExtraLarge
    case accessibilityExtraExtraLarge
    case accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge
    
    
    var category: UIContentSizeCategory {
        switch self {
        case .unspecified: return .unspecified
        case .extraSmall: return .extraSmall
        case .small: return .small
        case .medium: return .medium
        case .large: return .large
        case .extraLarge: return .extraLarge
        case .extraExtraLarge: return .extraExtraLarge
        case .extraExtraExtraLarge: return .extraExtraExtraLarge
        case .accessibilityMedium: return .accessibilityMedium
        case .accessibilityLarge: return .accessibilityLarge
        case .accessibilityExtraLarge: return .accessibilityExtraLarge
        case .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: return .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge
        case .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: return .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge
        }
    }
}

enum FontKeys: String {
    case homeTitleFont = "HomeTitleFont"
}


var CustomFontHolderCache: [CustomFontHolder] = []

CustomFontHolderCache.append(
    CustomFontHolder(
        id: FontKeys.homeTitleFont.rawValue,
        originalSize: 24,
        originalWeight: .bold,
        traitCollection: .accessibilityLarge
    )
)


var fontHolder = CustomFontHolderCache.first(where: { $0.id == FontKeys.homeTitleFont.rawValue })!

var dynamicFont = fontHolder.dynamicFont
var originalFont = fontHolder.originalFont
```